# Select columns dynamically in Azure ML model

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have deployed a model as a Webservice in Azure ML.Its a simple one and all it does is do a linear Regression .The underlying code is python . Now i need to pass which all columns have to selected as independent variables, dynamically, from the client side . How may i do this in Azure ML studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my understanding, I think you want to dynamically get the selected columns data via request the Azure ML webservice with some parameters on the client.

You can refer to the offical document [Use Azure Machine Learning Web Service Parameters](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/machine-learning-web-service-parameters/) and the blog [AzureML Web Service Parameters](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/machinelearning/2014/11/25/azureml-web-service-parameters/) to know how to set and use the web service parameters to implement your needs via add the selected column names as array into the json parameter `GlobalParameters`.

Meanwhile, there is a client sample on GitHub https://github.com/nk773/AzureML_RRSApp. Althought it was writen in Java, I think it is easy to understand, then you can rewrite in Python with `requests` package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!